# Drag a knob to 360 degree using green sock

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, gsap

I am trying to drag a circular knob from 0 to 360 degree using green sock library.
Adding a codepen below in which I have used bounds property which bound drag rotation from 0 to 359 degree but because of this when I start to drag from last quadrant(between 270 to 360 degree) then, the drag jumps to 1st quadrant(0 degree) and starts to drag from 0 degree. In the 1st, 2nd and 3rd quadrant the drag works properly but the 4th quadrant has some problem. 
I want to keep the bounds but also wants to drag if I drag between 270 to 360 degree. Please have a look over the codepen and help me out with this. Thank you.

**Steps to reproduce**
1. Drag till the last quadrant(between 270 degree to 360 degree) similar to clock between 9 - 12 and leave the mouse.

2. Press from last quadrant where you left the mouse, here you can see the drag starts from 0 degree.

```js
var rotationOffset = 90, //in case the dial's "home" position isn't at 0 degrees (pointing right). In this case, we use 90 degrees.
  RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI, //for converting radians to degrees
  adjusting;

TweenLite.set("#spinner", {
  transformOrigin: "center"
});

Draggable.create("#spinner", {
  type: "rotation",
  sticky: true,
  bounds: {
    minRotation: 0,
    maxRotation: 359,
  },
  trigger: "#svg",
  onPress: function(e) {
    if (!adjusting) {
      //figure out the angle from the pointer to the rotational origin (in degrees)
      var rotation = Math.atan2(this.pointerY - this.rotationOrigin.y, this.pointerX - this.rotationOrigin.x) * RAD2DEG;
      //set the rotation (with any offset that's necessary)
      TweenLite.set(this.target, {
        rotation: rotation + rotationOffset
      });
      //now we'll end the drag and start it again from this new place, but when we start again, it'll call the onPress of course so to avoid an endless loop, we use the "adjusting" variable to skip it in the triggered onPress.
      adjusting = true;
      this.endDrag(e);
      this.startDrag(e);
      adjusting = false;
    }
  },
  onDrag: function() {
    var rotation = Math.atan2(this.pointerY - this.rotationOrigin.y, this.pointerX - this.rotationOrigin.x) * RAD2DEG;
    $("#percent").text(rotation.toFixed(2))
  }
});
```

```css
#svg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  touch-action: none;
}

#spinner {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.big-circle {
  fill: dodgerblue;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.small-circle {
  fill: black;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/DrawSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>
<div id="percent">0</div>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <g id="spinner">
    <circle class="big-circle" cx="500" cy="500" r="200" />
    <circle class="small-circle" cx="500" cy="500" r="12" />
    <polyline class="line" points="500,500 500,300" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

[codepen of knob](https://codepen.io/irfanshaikh/pen/LajqqW)

*** UPDATED ***
I have updated the above codepen link with working solution if anybody comes in future to check similar problem. Thank you.

Comment: @mplungjan Rotate the circle then click 10 o'clock and you will see the issue.

Comment: Please update you question with the exact steps to reproduce. You do not mention click anywhere and drag works fine in Chrome at least

Comment: I have updated with steps to reproduce above and it is reproducible in chrome browser too.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you're using `bounds` and `trigger` parameters? 
If you remove them, your code will work accordingly.

```js
var rotationOffset = 90, //in case the dial's "home" position isn't at 0 degrees (pointing right). In this case, we use 90 degrees.
 RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI, //for converting radians to degrees
 adjusting;

TweenLite.set("#spinner", {transformOrigin: "center"});

Draggable.create("#spinner", {
  type: "rotation",
  sticky: true,
  /*bounds: {
    minRotation: 0,
    maxRotation: 360,
  },
  trigger: "#svg",*/
 onPress: function(e) {
  if (!adjusting) {
   //figure out the angle from the pointer to the rotational origin (in degrees)
   var rotation = Math.atan2(this.pointerY - this.rotationOrigin.y, this.pointerX - this.rotationOrigin.x) * RAD2DEG;
   //set the rotation (with any offset that's necessary)
   TweenLite.set(this.target, {rotation:rotation + rotationOffset});
   //now we'll end the drag and start it again from this new place, but when we start again, it'll call the onPress of course so to avoid an endless loop, we use the "adjusting" variable to skip it in the triggered onPress.
   adjusting = true;
   this.endDrag(e);
   this.startDrag(e);
   adjusting = false;
  }
 },
  onDrag: function(){
    var rotation = Math.atan2(this.pointerY - this.rotationOrigin.y, this.pointerX - this.rotationOrigin.x) * RAD2DEG;
    
  }
});
```

```css
#svg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 touch-action: none;
  
}

#spinner {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.big-circle {
  fill: dodgerblue;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.small-circle {
  fill: black;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<div id="percent">0</div>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <g id="spinner">
    <circle class="big-circle" cx="500" cy="500" r="200" />
    <circle class="small-circle" cx="500" cy="500" r="12" />
    <polyline class="line" points="500,500 500,300" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

https://greensock.com/docs/Utilities/Draggable/static.create()

Comment: We don't want the drag to cross from 359 degree to 0 degree. It should stop at 360 degree and the user have to again drag back to 0 degree if he wants to.

Comment: Updated the codepen above on my question with working solution.Thank you.